# How to delete instantly SPACE from an edittext if a user presses the space?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an edittext, and a textwatcher that watches if SPACE arrived or not. If its a SPACE I would like to delete that instantly. Or if its a space I want to make sure it doesnt appear but indicate somehow (seterror, toast) for the user that space is not allowed.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   //---//
                  }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        });
```

I cannot define onkeydown in the afterTextChaned method, since it gives me an error.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {

                }
    }
```

So it is not working (syntax error, misplaced construct for the `int keyCode`.

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: what'd the error you mentioned?

Comment: No error in the logcat, it is a simple syntax error.

Comment: Do you want to show the entered space character `then` delete it or do you simply want to make sure the user doesn't enter spaces in the `EditText`?

Comment: I want to make sure the user doesnt enter space, but if it happens I want to make an error message appear for the edittext (a seterror message). I my case its not obvious that SPACE cannot be used, so I would like to warn the user if he/she uses SPACE.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The solution is as usually much simpler:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         ed.setText(result);
         ed.setSelection(result.length());
         // alert the user
    }
}
```

This shouldn't have the problems of the previous attempts.

Comment: Ok, how about this, I'll just paste `this line with spaces` inside the textbox? Huh, now what? :D (I'm not trying to be mean, :) I am not sure so I'm asking...You might want to check the entire string for spaces.

Comment: @st0le My code was only for the case when the user enters the text character by character. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Your first code is what I need but if I go to the middle of the text the space appears, so it only works if the cursor is at the end of the text.

Comment: Second code is not working for me. If I press space it appears.

Comment: @JaniBela Sorry about that I forgot that case. I've updated my answer with a simpler solution that should work no matter what.

Comment: Simple is always best;-) Nice solution!

Comment: @zeeks Add a TextWatcher(which requires you to implement 3 methods) to your EditText's and then add the code from my answer in the afterTextChanged() method of the TextWatcher. In the question you can see how to add the watcher.

Comment: This method is surely not working for me, phone got hanged. keyboard was showing there for infinitely even if i closed that app. Need to restart my phone! it's actually getting recursive in my view

Comment: @JimitPatel I doubt that simply using the code I posted (with nothing else added) could exhibit the behavior you mention. Please post a new question with your current code, before that try debugging the app and watch what you get as text in the TextWatcher.

Comment: @Luksprog, I am using your piece of code in conjuction of RXjava

Comment: @JimitPatel You should definitely post a new question(along with the RxJava code you use)  as your problem is out of scope here.

Comment: @Luksprog, probably you are right which hold me from down voting to your answers :D. Nonetheless, I wrote down in comment because if someone failed while using it in future they will understand and probably will stop them from down voting

Answer (score 3):

`setSelection` is there to set the cursor again at the end of your `EditText`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {}
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {}
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    if(editText.getText().toString().contains(" ")){ editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().replaceAll(" " , ""));
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Spaces Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }});
```

Comment: Is "ist" a typo in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean editclicked =false ;

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        editclicked = false ;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        editclicked = true;
    });
```

Put this as a separate function:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (editclicked) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error because of enclosing type or somekind of that.

Answer (score 2):

My relatively simple solution for instant whitespace deletion **without removing `spannables`** (styles) in `EditText`:

1. Remove at start:

   ```
       @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)); i++) { ; }
       s.replace(0, i, "");
   }
   ```

---

*Basically that's it, but you can also do:*

2. Remove at start (without interrupting first input):

   ```
       @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       String text = s.toString();
       if(!text.trim().isEmpty()){
           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)); i++) { ; }
           s.replace(0, i, "");
       }
   }
   ```

---

3. Removing at start and end (allow 1 whitespace at end for convinient input):

   ```
       @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       int i;
       //remove at start
       for (i = 0; i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)); i++) { ; }
       s.replace(0, i, "");
       //remove at end, but allow one whitespace character
       for (i = s.length(); i > 1 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i-1)) && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i-2)); i--) { ; }
       s.replace(i, s.length(), "");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String result = s.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart() - (s.length() - result.length());
        editText.setText(result);
        editText.setSelection(Math.max(0,Math.min(pos, result.length())));
        editText.setError("No spaces allowed");
    }
}
```

\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Setting selection like this, allow you to enter or paste text in middle of edittext without loosing cursor position

Answer (score 0):

For removing the space instantly you can achieve it by two ways.

One simple solution you can set the digits to your edit text.

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
```

second way you can set a filter

```
EditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });


InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
 public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
   if (Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
    return "";
   }
  }
  return null;


      }
     }
```

Comment: Note that returning null here is the correct thing to do if you want to keep the text as is, despite being the most confusing thing ever. I can't wait to learn Kotlin...

Answer (score 0):

One more simple way to achieve this using the input Filter

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
                return "";
            }
            return source;
        }
    }});
```

This will remove the space entered by the user immediately and gives appearance like space is disabled.