# How to restrict some character in editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Please don't hurry to mark this message as "duplicated".
I can't find  an appropriate  example.
Suppose I'd like to restrict the char "{" in editText.

Let's consider a few variants of my code. I tried them on emulator only.

```
       editName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String txt=s.toString();
            int len=txt.length();
            toastDebug("len="+myIntToStr(len));
            if (len>0) {
                try {
                    int pos=txt.indexOf("{");
                    if (pos>=0) s.replace(pos,pos+1,"");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
```

If I type "{" quiickly  it leads to "stackOverFlow" crash.
Suppose I type "abcd{{{{{{{" slowly. For the first view it looks okay, no "{" in editText.
But if I type backspace, it does not remove  "abcd", it removes those invisible "{{{{{"

I tried to change the editText inside of "afterTextChanged". The code below causes stackOverflowError again.

```
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String txt=s.toString();
            int len=txt.length();
            if (len>0) {
                try {
                   editName.setText(txt)
                   or
                   s.clear
                   s.append(txt)
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
```

Many examples with [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android) clear my editText after I type "{".

Well, I modified this code as follows:

```
    editName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filterName });

    private InputFilter filterName = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (source==null) return null;
            return source.toString().replace("{","");
    }
};
```

Now it works. But my android:maxLength="25" does not work.
It is possible to type any numbers of characters.

So I am puzzled how can I restrict simple character in editText.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757991/how-to-delete-instantly-space-from-an-edittext-if-a-user-presses-the-space ?

Comment: @Niaz , have you tried with regular expressions?

Comment: Luksprog, as I said, if I change editText inside of afterTextChanged block (like in example you mentioned), I got "stackoverflow". Yes. It is only replace chars in editable to space. But if I replace "{" to "", then I got strange behaviour of backspace

Comment: Gödel77, I could not understand the thought concerning regular expresions.

Comment: I've run some tests with the code I linked to and it works, it wouldn't allow you to input the `"{"` character(I also don't get any exception no matter how fast I enter characters, the delete process works). The only change was to escape `{` because it will be used in a regular exception, so instead of "{" it will be "\\{".

Comment: Luksprog, Wow! your example really works okay! There is "replaceAll" in your example instead of  "replace" in mine. I try to understand... Thank you very much for help! If you place this code as an answer, I will check it as valid.  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String result = s.toString().replaceAll("\\{", "");
                if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
                    editName.setText(result);
                    editName.setSelection(result.length());
                }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restrict the characters that the user can enter in the `EditText` by setting a `TextWatcher` on the widget and inserting the logic below:

```
// we are interested in this callback
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String result = s.toString().replaceAll("\\{", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         edit.setText(result); // "edit" being the EditText on which the TextWatcher was set
         edit.setSelection(result.length()); // to set the cursor at the end of the current text             
    }
}
```

The `\\` is required(and for other characters) because the `{` character has a special meaning in a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by `xml` as well

```
android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,@,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"
```

**or**

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

Which u want put here.

Comment: thanks, I know about such solution but it does not work for other (than English) languages

Comment: Maybe UTF8 chars works for other languages in digit="...", but it would be more comfortable to exclude couple characters, than to set all available set of chars

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is `android:maxLength` actually is a `InputFilter` that added to your `EditText`. so if you want to add more `InputFilter`, you must get the current `InputFilter` array of your `EditText` and append it with your own `InputFIlter`. I do this and this works.

```
EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        InputFilter filterName = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source==null) return null;
            return source.toString().replace("{","");
        }
    };

    //Get current Input Filter from EditText
    InputFilter[] oldInputFilter = editName.getFilters();
    //Create arrays for new InputFilter
    InputFilter[] newInputFilter = new InputFilter[oldInputFilter.length+1];
    //Copy all old Input Filter to new one
    System.arraycopy(oldInputFilter, 0, newInputFilter, 0, oldInputFilter.length);
    //Add your own input filter
    newInputFilter[newInputFilter.length-1] = filterName;
    //Set the new Input Filter
    editName.setFilters(newInputFilter);
```

Comment: Unfortunately length of editText is still unlimited and after typing abcd{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{ backspace does not remove dbca, but only these invisible {{{{{{{ somewhere...

Comment: Are you still using the TextWatcher from first and second code?

Comment: Are you already commented the editName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filterName }); from third code?

Comment: Oh, yes. I have commented it now. The maxlength of editText is okay, but strange backspace is still there. Frankly I could not understand your code... If I replace "{" with space, all is okay, but extra spaces were added...

Comment: Bad news is that Arrays.copyOf in your code does not work on Android 2.2. But my goal was to write an app for all Android versions....

Comment: I have replaced the Arrays.copyOf to alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

```
The above correct answer only work for one EditText.
But this work for all the EditText in you XML.

        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
            boolean canEnterSpace = false;

            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                if(_edtUsername.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    canEnterSpace = false;
                }

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                    char currentChar = source.charAt(i);

                    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(currentChar) || currentChar == '{') {
                        builder.append(currentChar);
                        canEnterSpace = false;
                    }

                    if(Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && canEnterSpace) {
                        builder.append(currentChar);
                    }


                }
                return builder.toString();          
            }

        };
        _edtUsername.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
        _edtFirstName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
        _edtLastName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I replaced with "**.com**" to ""

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.edittextdemo.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

// Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
        edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String currentStr = s.toString().replaceAll(".com", "");
                if (!s.toString().equals(currentStr)) {
                    edt.setText(currentStr); 
                    edt.setSelection(currentStr.length());              
                }
            }
        });
    }
```