# How can I replace one note with a different note as the user is typing (replace “space” with “-”

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am using a tag system similar to SO, and instead of forcing the user to find the dash in their keyboard I want space to automatically be translated to a dash.

I am trying to implement it with this textWatcher, but the app doesn't let me type the space bar (it kinda flashes but nothing happens.

```
        imageTagsInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                imageTagsInput.removeTextChangedListener(this)
                imageTagsInput.setText(imageTagsInput.text.toString().replace(" ","-"))
                imageTagsInput.addTextChangedListener(this)
                imageTagsInput.setSelection(imageTagsInput.length())


            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

        })
```

And this is the xml of the EditText:
               `android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789- &#160;"`

Comment: remove this thing from your xml android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789- &#160;"
It might work now

Comment: But I want to limit what characters could be used (Latin characters, numbers and some other specific characters).

Comment: you can do it other too but just remove and try whether you get what you want or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828520/8101634
see this link it will help you restrict your characters

Comment: @primo I just tried removing it, it still doesn't work

Comment: keep it as it is how you kept your xml file and then see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this in afterTextChanged

```
  String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "-");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         ed.setText(result);
         ed.setSelection(result.length());
         // alert the user
    }
```

For more info see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9759600/8101634)

Comment: It doesn't work. Both this and my original code work with other characters, it's something to do with the space I believe

Comment: you can do something like detect if spacebar is pressed then replace it with dash

Comment: I found a way around my issue that works for me. I needed the text to change to compare it with existing tags. While it doesn't work for me for changing the actual text, I am just using it to change the text I use for the comparison, so while the user is typing spaces the search functions searched for the same string only with dashes instead.
I appreciate the effort.

Comment: add your answer if you found out your solution

Comment: I haven't found the solution, just found a different approach that satisfies my goal, but it doesn't solve my original issue.